# starting data collation after a particular timestamp

Tags: awk, timestamp

I have several files with 26 columns separated with commas.  There are several hundred rows.  Each row has a time stamp in the third column.  I want to average like columns in all the files starting after the 6 pm time stamp and copy the averaged data to a new file. Two of the rows are shown below.  The date and time are separated with by white space.  I can use AWK to do the averaging it's the starting after 6pm that has me confused.

Any help appreciated.

```
1,0102,3/1/2013 3:44:50 PM ,3586,20.88,20.51,0.36,0.0,2777,0.083,0.377,0.294,0.0,0.775,0.6,0.60,STABLE,0.01,0.01,0.812,0.812,989,713,755,553,799,
2,0102,3/1/2013 3:59:50 PM ,2727,20.91,20.63,0.28,0.0,2215,0.067,0.302,0.234,0.0,0.812,0.5,0.60,STABLE,0.05,0.06,0.000,0.812,2385,1713,1810,1270,1910,
```

Comment: What are you using for this?

Comment: I'm new at scripting.  the raw files (.CSV) are generated by an instrument that collects metabolic data on mice over a 72 hour period.  I average the data by groups and then import the averaged data into visualization/statistical software to test for differences between these groups.  In the past I would copy and paste raw files into Excel and do the averaging which is a clunky way to do this.  I have found AWK one liners that look like it should do the job.  But I need to average data starting at similar times or I introduce too much noise to "see" little differences.  Sorry for the wordy ans

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
BEGIN { 
 FS=","; 
 ok=0 
} 

$3~/[6,7,8,9,10,11]:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ PM/ { ok=1 } 

ok==1 { print }
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This works but unfortunately prints only PM data starting after 6 PM.  I really need awk to look for the first occurrence after 6 PM and print the entire file after that. The files are data collected in a 72 hour period.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've changed the script somewhat so that awk reads multiple files and stores the results in a new file'test'          awk -F"\," '$3~/[6,7,8,9,10,11]:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ PM/ { print }' *.CSV > test

Comment: You could replace "print" with a variable switch, something like: 
BEGIN { FS=","; ok=0 }
$3~/[6,7,8,9,10,11]:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ PM/ { ok=1 }
ok==1 { print }

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!!  So that I can learn from this, would you explain what the ok=0, ok=1 and ok==1 is doing?

Comment: First you set the variable ok=0 (BEGIN), then when you find the first pattern match you set ok=1 (second row), thus the last pattern just checks if the variable ok is 0 or 1 and if it is 1 it prints the full row...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It makes total sense now.